# Run Laravel from subfolder using apache Alias

Tags: apache, laravel

Im trying to run laravel from subfolder on my vps below is my configuration but it return too many redirect

apache alias

```
Alias /stockapp/ "/var/www/html/stockapp/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/stockapp/public/">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all   
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stockapp

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: did you confirm that your laravel code is working ?

Comment: yes laravel is working if i run from root

Comment: could you post the index.php in your public folder. Issue seems to be there

Comment: its same i did not make any changes in index.php laravel v5.0

Comment: same Alias setting work for WordPress but not for laravel